# CSS how to make a perfectly alligned left (or right) border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to accomplish in pure CSS is setting the left border of a Bootstrap 3 panel:

[image]

Here is the strandard way to do it:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading.standard {
    border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here is using pseudo-elements:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading.pseudo:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Result is not OK in both cases. With the standard way the border is kinda "oblique" (only in bottom-right corner, why?), with pseudo-elements I can make the rectangle margins negative (i.e. -1, -1) but then I need to know the exact height of the heading:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the exact height of the heading, only the height of the borders. So, for example, if the borders on top and bottom are both 1px:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading.pseudo:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sbr3q2tq/

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working; pseudo-element height does not expand to the bottom, event setting it to -1.

Comment: @gremo I have edited my answer, you need to remove `height: 100%`

Comment: @SteveSanders height: auto; also works, in case OP needs to overwrite a different behavior.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Out of curiosity, what's the glitch when using border-left property?

Comment: @gremo that's just how CSS borders work. View this, it should help visualize it for you: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh

Comment: @SteveSanders yep I understand, but what about the top left border? It doesn't show the "glitch", am I right?

Comment: @gremo that's because the top border is coming from a different element, the panel. (not the panel header) The panel header only has a bottom border